# kendo ui Grid unselect after click next button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Good morning! When you take action by clicking the delete button on the grid the first time I run the following below:

```
destroy: function (options) {
     var data =  JSON.stringify(options.data.models);
     data = data.replace('[','').replace(']','');
     alert(data);
      /*$.ajax({
            url: '".$url."',
            data: {data: data}, 
            success: function (result) {
               alert(result);
               $('#show_msgs').html(result);
            }
      });*/
},
```

He performs standard and move to destroy the datasource perfectly until he disappeared from the grid, but when I click another item to delete what I have noticed in the destroy the dataSource to access the data it has brought the values ​​of the previous item, the next code below:

```
{name: 'excluir',text: '',title: '', className: 'bt-excluir',imageClass: 'k-icon k-delete',
    click: function(e) {
       var grid = this;
       var fields = grid.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields;
       var tr = $(e.target).closest('tr'); 
       var data = this.dataItem(tr); 
       var model = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
       var array = {};

       $.each(fields, function (idx, elem) {
            if(elem.type === 'date'){
                model[idx] = kendo.toString(model[idx],'yyyy-MM-dd');
            }
            if(elem.type === 'datetime'){
                model[idx] = kendo.toString(model[idx],'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
            }
            array[idx] = model[idx];
       });
       var data = JSON.stringify(array);

       window.content(template(data)); 
       window.open().center();  

       $('.k-confirm-true').click(function(){
            alert(model.toSource());
            grid.dataSource.remove(model);
            model.set('selected',!1);
            delete model.selected;
            grid.clearSelection();
            grid.dataSource.sync();
            window.close();
        })
        $('.k-confirm-false').click(function(){
            window.close();
        })
    }
 },
```

This is result of first alert(data) in destroy:

```
[{id_estadio:4, nome_estadio:"Ninfa IV", borrifa:"\x01"}]
```

This is result of secod alert(data) in destroy:

```
[{id_estadio:4, nome_estadio:"Ninfa IV", borrifa:"\x01"}, {id_estadio:3, nome_estadio:"Ninfa III", borrifa:"\x01"},]
```

and in the click of a button it only passes the corresponding item that line!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying but seems overcomplicated. From similar problems it seems to me that you are not notifying the DataSource that the initial deleted item was actually removed so KendoUI still thinks that is pending (`dirty` is set to `true`). When you remove an element you need to invoke `op.success()` where `op` is the argument received in the `destroy` function of your transport. Try putting a running example in JSFiddle or JSBin and I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just put in the destroy the following line:
options.success (options.data.models) and worked perfectly, now I wonder what suggestions can you give me about that when I run the following line: grid.dataSource.remove (date), in the onclick of the button removes it already element of the grid and this happens only after the ajax request was successful